# sample without replacement

Tags: sample

A population contains 10 units, labelled U1, U2, U3,.......U10. The value of a character Y under study, for Ui is Yi(1<=i<=10). In order to estimate the population mean, Y*, a sample of size 4 is drawn in the following manner:

1. A simple random sample of size 2 is drawn without replacement from the units U2,U3,......U9;
   2)The sample drawn in the first step is augmented by the units U1 and U10. Based on the above sample in the second part, suggest an unbiased estimator of Y* and obtain its variance.

The most basic question I want to ask here is not about the unbiased estimator, but how is Y related to U1,.....?
'Character under study for Yi' what does the phrase indicate?

Comment: $Y$ is a random variable, which can be characterized as [associating a number with each unit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/54894/919).

Comment: Based on the understanding, I developed from the link above. $U1,U2....$ can be considered as the tickets in the box and $Y1,Y2....$ are the values of the change in investment. right?

Comment: So, $U1,U2,....$ are the random variables that we will proceed with

Comment: The $U_i$ are the outcomes.  The map $Y:U_i\to Y_i$ is a single random variable.